# How can I access amz-sp-api gem models in gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-selling-partner-api

I'm a junior dev trying to use the vendor-direct-fulfillment-orders-api-model for the Amz-sp-api gem and I can't seem to figure out how to build the sub gem for the desired model. I have installed the Amz-sp-api gem.

Here's a question that is related to the gem, although can't find anything else that is related to the actual usage of the models: [Amazon Selling Partner API in Ruby returns MissingAuthenticationToken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67510253/amazon-selling-partner-api-in-ruby-returns-missingauthenticationtoken)

Here's a link to the actual gem: https://github.com/ericcj/amz_sp_api#getting-started

Any help with this would be great! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to build the 'sub gem'; all the models were generated already and are stored on the repo.
[Here](https://github.com/ericcj/amz_sp_api/blob/main/lib/vendor-direct-fulfillment-orders-api-model/api/vendor_orders_api.rb) is the model you are looking for.